# Defining a Function in Python to Insert Date in to a SQLite Table?

Tags: python, sqlite

So I am pretty new to the world of programming, I have gone through the basics of python and am moving on to try and use python and sqlite to make a small program.

I have read through the SQLite documentation and I understand how to insert and call data, but for doing this multiple times it seems like using a function to accomplish this is logically the answer, and this is where I have hit a roadblock.

So far this is what I have come up with based on my own intuition of trying to translate the code in to a function:

```
i_date = input('Input Date as YYYY-MM-DD > ')
i_trans = input('Select Buy or Sell >')
i_symbol = input('Input Stock Ticker > ')
i_qty = input('Input Qty to be Purchased > ')
i_price = input('Input Buy/Sell Price > ')

update_tbl = ('i_date' + 'i_trans' + 'i_symbol' + 'i_qty' + 'i_price')


def update_table(date, trans, symbol, qty, price):
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', update_tbl)

update_table(update_tbl)
```

The result is that it definitely seems to be passing date on to the function, but only the very first item.  The error it generates is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQL.py", line 25, in <module>
    update_table(update_tbl)
TypeError: update_table() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'trans', 'symbol', 'qty', 
and 'price'
```

I am unsure if the error lies with how I am adding all of the variables together as a single variable at update_tbl, or if the error lies with how I am passing it on to the function.  I originally tried separating each variable with just commas and that returned the same result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: So far this is the only thing I have gotten to successfully pass the parameters on to the function:

```
i_date = input('Input Date as YYYY-MM-DD > ')
i_trans = input('Select Buy or Sell > ')
i_symbol = input('Input Stock Ticker > ')
i_qty = input('Input Qty to be Purchased > ')
i_price = input('Input Buy/Sell Price > ')

update_tbl = [i_date, i_trans, i_symbol, i_qty, i_price]


def update_table(date, trans, symbol, qty, price):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', update_tbl)

update_table(i_date, i_trans, i_symbol, i_qty, i_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the SQLite Query in general is:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2 ,..) VALUES( value1, value2 ,...)
```

For you it would be:

```
update_tbl = [i_date, i_trans, i_symbol, i_qty, i_price] #save variables into a list

def update_table(update_tbl):
    c.execute(f'INSERT INTO stocks (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES({update_tbl[0]}, {update_tbl[1]}, {update_tbl[2]}, {update_tbl[3]}, {update_tbl[4]})')
```

Comment: Ah i see your function takes to many arguments. You just need to pass your list "update_tbl" to the function. I edited my answer.

Comment: That returned an error of too few arguments.  I updated my original post, so far that is the only way I have been able to pass the arguments on to the function, I suppose I don't *need* to combine the variables in to a single variable.

Comment: Thats true, it is not necessary, but it makes it a bit more dynamic. In your updated original post i can see, that you didnt change the "c.executemany" command like i posted above. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that, while using c.executemany, the code I updated with wouldn't work, but once I changed it to c.execute it worked immediately.

Comment: Further fussing with the code I also notice that changing update_tbl to a tuple an inputting the variables in the call to update_table as update_tbl[0], etc, works as well as listing the individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create the update_tbl inside the function with the parameters you pass to the function. The problem with your first solution is that you are creating a list of 1 item. This is because you are concatenating all the inputs into 1 string.

```
i_date = input('Input Date as YYYY-MM-DD > ')
i_trans = input('Select Buy or Sell > ')
i_symbol = input('Input Stock Ticker > ')
i_qty = input('Input Qty to be Purchased > ')
i_price = input('Input Buy/Sell Price > ')


def update_table(date, trans, symbol, qty, price):
    update_tbl = [date, trans, symbol, qty, price]
    c.execute('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', update_tbl)


update_table(i_date, i_trans, i_symbol, i_qty, i_price)
```

Comment: Just for my own clarification here, what does this change specifically? The function already works if I pass the individual variables the way I have it in my most recent edit.

Comment: The parameters (`date`, `trans`, `symbol`, `qty`, `price`) are actually used. To see the difference, call the function with different values e.g. `update_table("2020-01-01", "buy", "MSFT", "1", "213.67")`. You will see that this function will use these values. In the original, the old values would be used.